# grunticon installing issue in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gruntjs, npm

When I installing grunticon from terminal window in Ubuntu 14.04
its always return fail.
here is my command :

sudo npm cache clean

sudo npm install -g grunt-grunticon

here is my debug log

11668 info postuninstall directory-colorfy@2.0.5

11669 verbose about to build /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-grunticon/node_modules/grunticon-lib

11670 info /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-grunticon/node_modules/grunticon-lib unbuild

11671 info preuninstall grunticon-lib@1.0.2

11672 info uninstall grunticon-lib@1.0.2

11673 verbose false,/usr/local/lib/node_modules,/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-grunticon/node_modules unbuild grunticon-lib@1.0.2

11674 info postuninstall grunticon-lib@1.0.2

11675 verbose about to build /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-grunticon

11676 info /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-grunticon unbuild

11677 info preuninstall grunt-grunticon@2.2.0

11678 info uninstall grunt-grunticon@2.2.0

11679 verbose true,/usr/local/lib/node_modules,/usr/local/lib/node_modules unbuild grunt-grunticon@2.2.0

11680 info postuninstall grunt-grunticon@2.2.0

11681 error 404 'filamentgroup' is not in the npm registry.

11681 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it

11681 error 404

11681 error 404 Note that you can also install from a

11681 error 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

11682 error System Linux 3.13.0-55-generic

11683 error command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-grunticon"

11684 error cwd /var/www/html/aidsvu-v2-git/AIDSVu-v2/wp-content/themes/genesis-av2

11685 error node -v v0.10.25

11686 error npm -v 1.3.10

11687 error code E404

11688 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon/issues/276) thread on github helped resolve this for me. I just ran `npm update -g` then re-ran `npm install grunt-grunticon --save-dev`.